# Writing a script with ping information into an excel or .csv file

Tags: linux, awk

I would like to create a table of min/avg/max ping data using a script.

The input would be a .txt of host names and their locations, the output should be a table of those names and their ip address and max, avg and min ping of the command `ping -c 10 example.com`

It would be something similar to this:

```sh
awk -F"time=" 'NR==2 || NR==3 || NR==4 {gsub(/ms/,X,$2);print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specs aren't very clear, but I *think* this might be what you want...

Assuming that the list of host names is called `hostlist` and the CSV file is `pings.csv` try this:

```
while read -r h; do ping -c 10 $h; done<hostlist |  awk 'BEGIN{printf "host,min,avg,max\n"} /PING/{host=$2};  $1=="rtt"{split($4,a,"/");printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n",host,a[1],a[2],a[3]}'  > pings.csv
```

Read the host list line by line:
`while read -r h; do ping -c 10 $h; done<hostlist` and ping each host ....

Pipe the entire output to awk.

Have `awk` print a "header row":

`BEGIN{printf "host,min,avg,max\n"}`

If a row of output matches PING save the hostname:

`/PING/{host=$2};`

From the last row (my ping starts that line with `rtt`) filter the times:

`$1=="rtt"{split($4,a,"/");`

Then print the whole data:

`printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n",host,a[1],a[2],a[3]}'`

and redirect it to the CSV

`> pings.csv`

Caution: this doesn't have ANY error handling at all.

Comment: Thanks so much! And also for the detailed explanation!